# How do I make the CLI run on dedicated graphics?

Tags: command-line, gentoo, graphics, monitors, amd

I just finished my Gentoo minimal install and the first thing I wonder is why I get no picture. I did have signal on the live CD, so that was pretty odd. I plugged the monitor into the Intel HD Graphics HDMI output instead, and there was my picture.

There's just this issue, I have 3 monitors. I need the AMD drivers, so I go ahead and install the proprietary ones, because I have the best experience with those. In order to do that, I had to recompile the kernel with some settings off and on to enable the AMD KMS. I have no idea what it is, but it worked fine following [this guide](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/xorg-config.xml) (for my Sapphire Radeon HD 7970).

I'm aiming to install XFCE 4, so I also had Xorg installed.

```
emerge xorg-server ati-drivers
```

I ran `startx` and got the picture I expected on the monitor plugged into the Intel HD port. Now I stopped the x-server again and ran `aticonfig --initial` and rebooted. I already know that aticonfig only updates xorg.conf and when I started x again it appeared on the correct monitor. The only thing bothering me now is that the CLI before starting x is STILL on the integrated graphics monitor. How do I get this sent to the dedicated graphics card as well?

Comment: Did you tell your BIOS to use the off-board graphics first?

Comment: @Ignacio I have a feature to disable it completely, and I did that, but it doesn't seem to work.
GRUB and the BIOS appears on my AMD monitors as well

Comment: The Linux console is managed by kernel proper - probably the on-board card gets initialized first and kernel decides to use that instead of the AMD card. Building the driver as a module and loading it only later might help.

Comment: @peterph So you suggest I compile the Intel drivers as a module? Wouldn't that just render me unable to install the AMD drivers in the first place? Of course if I used the KMS thing it should work. Hmm. I'll give it a spin.

Comment: I don't understand why not having Intel drivers built in should prevent you from using AMD. And I'm not really sure it has anything to do with KMS.

Comment: Have you compiled the kernel option `vga switcharoo`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [fbcon](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt), you would need this option:

```
3. fbcon=map:<0123>

        This is an interesting option. It tells which driver gets mapped to
        which console. The value '0123' is a sequence that gets repeated until
        the total length is 64 which is the number of consoles available. In
        the above example, it is expanded to 012301230123... and the mapping
        will be:

        tty | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...         fb  | 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 ...

        ('cat /proc/fb' should tell you what the fb numbers are)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `xrandr` to see if you correctly detected all possible displays. If it shows them correctly, use `xrandr --output "***" --primary` to set whichever display you want as primary.

`"***"` is one of the detected displayed types (example: `DVI-0`).